How do I disable swipe for next video on YouTube?
Recently, the YouTube mobile app on Android added a feature where you can swipe up or down on a video to switch to a new video, similar to YouTube Shorts. This has led to me accidentally switching videos and YouTube forgetting where I'm at in a 2 hour video.
How do I disable the swipe for new video feature on YouTube for Android?
https://youtu.be/EzgwmMxGtIY?si=vDlMsP34NsTTwpoL

If you have autoplay on the "swipe up for next video" does not appear. I use autoplay anyways but if you don't it's that or have an annoying pop up we'll before the video ends. Hope this helps.

Swiping still switches videos even if I enable autoplay.

I'm using a Fold 6 and swiping with autoplay on on the front display or the main screen doesn't skip videos. On front display only swipe up does anything and that's bring up recommend videos and on the main display only swiping up or down just takes you out of or puts you in fullscreen. Sorry it's not the same for you, maybe it's different depending on what android you're using.

Looks like this feature is a limited test by YouTube and not everyone got it: "We presume this change is a limited test, as we could not spot it on multiple devices. We could neither locate support documentation nor a release changelog highlighting this change." //cc: @Stevoisiak
